# Character only moves continuosly when both button is held and mouse is moving

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I'm trying to get the code to accept that the user has a key held, and continuously update. However, it only does one update and then carries out the rest of the code, ignoring the user's input.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import math

pygame.init()
black = (0,0,0)
Window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')


FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.Rect(0,0,800,500)
player = pygame.Rect(725,425, 25,25)
playerx = player.x
playery = player.y
jumping = False
onground = True
while True:
    onground = True
    jumping = False
    Window.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(Window, pygame.color.Color('Royal Blue'), player, 0)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_w]:
            jumping = True
            onground = False
        elif keys[K_a]:
            player.move_ip(-1,0)
        elif keys[K_d]:
            player.move_ip(2,0)

    if jumping == True and onground == False:
        player.move_ip(0,-1)
        if keys[K_a]:
            player.move_ip(-2,-1)
        elif keys[K_d]:
            player.move_ip(2,-1)
    elif (jumping == False and onground == False) or playery > 412:
        player.move_ip(0,1)
        jumping = False

    print player.copy()

    player.clamp_ip(background)
    pygame.display.flip()
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Your clock ticks outside the main loop, and you reset your flags every time.

Comment: Use more `print` to see values in varaibles and in which `if/elif` you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_w]:
        jumping = True
        onground = False
    elif keys[K_a]:
        player.move_ip(-1,0)
    elif keys[K_d]:
        player.move_ip(2,0)
```

inside

```
for e in pygame.event.get():
```

so it is executed only when there are some events like mouse move or key was pressed.

Keyboard events are created only when you press/unpress key - not when you keep pressed.
So this  `for` loop works and execute anything inside only when you move mouse or press keys.

My version of your code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#import math

# CONSTANTS - uppercase

BLACK = (0,0,0)
FPS = 60
BLUE = pygame.color.Color('Royal Blue')

# GAME

pygame.init()
# window - variables - always lowercase
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

background = pygame.Rect(0,0,800,500)
player = pygame.Rect(725,425, 25,25)
playerx = player.x
playery = player.y

# mainloop

fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

jumping = False
onground = True

gaming = True
paused = False

while gaming:
    onground = True
    jumping = False

    # --- (all) events ---

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            gaming = False
        elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                gaming = False
            elif e.key == K_SPACE:
                paused = not paused

    # --- (events and) moves ---

    if not paused:
        # not in `for e in event`
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_w]:
            jumping = True
            onground = False
        elif keys[K_a]:
            player.move_ip(-1,0)
        elif keys[K_d]:
            player.move_ip(2,0)

        if jumping == True and onground == False:
            player.move_ip(0,-1)
            if keys[K_a]:
                player.move_ip(-2,-1)
            elif keys[K_d]:
                player.move_ip(2,-1)
        elif (jumping == False and onground == False) or playery > 412:
            player.move_ip(0,1)
            jumping = False

    print player #.copy() # why copy ???

    #player.clamp_ip(background) # I don't need it

    # --- (all) draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, player, 0)
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    fps_clock.tick(FPS)

# the end

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: This helped me a lot actually. Thank you so much! I didn't realize what the flaw in my code. 
The print player.copy() was used to show the coordinates of the player for troubleshooting purposes, but I forgot to get rid of it when I wrote this. Once again, Thank you so very much!